# Python requests library added an additional header "Accept-Encoding: identity"

Tags: python, http, http-headers, python-requests

This is my code.

```
import requests
from sys import exit
proxies = {
    "http": "127.0.0.1:8888",
    "https": "127.0.0.1:8888",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}


login_page = "http://www.test.com/login/"
r = requests.get(login_page, proxies = proxies, headers = headers)
original_cookies = r.cookies
exit(0)
```

This is what I got from fiddler2. As you can see, it added an additional header `Accept-Encoding: identity`.

```
GET http://www.test.com/login/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.test.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
```

I'm using Python 3.3.2 on Windows 7 64 bit and requests 1.2.3.

Anyone can give some suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: That is extremely odd. What version of requests do you use? Their repository doesn't have the word "identity" in it other than in the docs.

Comment: Yes I searched the repository and got the same result as you described. I use requests 1.2.3. I found a link and seems my issue exists in that page: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/821#issuecomment-17791431

Comment: I'm willing to bet (not a huge amount…) it's the proxy that's adding the extra header, not `requests`. What do you have running at localhost:8888?

Comment: And it looks like I might lose that bet; it may be caused by the way `requests` merges headers for the proxy and headers for the target server… If you're pretty sure #821 is your problem, you should post that as an answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: I use the fiddler2's built-in proxy server to debug my http communications. I'm not sure if it's fiddler2 added the header, however I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Try printing `r.request.headers` : those are the headers that `requests` *thinks* it sent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This originates deep within the bowels of [`http.client`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Lib/http/client.py#l1009), which is used by `urllib3` which is used by `requests`.

`http.client` actually [checks](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Lib/http/client.py#l1086) if there is already an `accept-encoding` in the headers dictionary passed, and if there is it skips adding the `identity` header - the only problem is that what is passed as headers dictionary is something like this:

```
CaseInsensitiveDict({b'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', ...})
```

So why is it not working? `requests` [encodes](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v1.2.3/requests/models.py#L336) the header names, and as in python3 a `str` object compared to a `bytes` object always is `False`, the check performed in `http.client` fails...

If you really want to get rid of the additional header, the quickest way would be to either comment out [line 340 in requests/models.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v1.2.3/requests/models.py#L340), or monkeypatch `requests.models.PreparedRequest.prepare_headers`

*edit*:
this seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/09c52e7282f53f7d38cc2ab268043ff232960448/requests/models.py#L371) in the (not yet released) 2.0 branch of requests

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@mata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350899/mata)'s answer, I've been able monkey patched `HTTPConnection.putheader` to ignore `Accept-Encoding: identity` in my particular case:

```py
from http.client import HTTPConnection

def drop_accept_encoding_on_putheader(http_connection_putheader):
    def wrapper(self, header, *values):
        if header == "Accept-Encoding" and "identity" in values:
            return
        return http_connection_putheader(self, header, *values)

    return wrapper

HTTPConnection.putheader = drop_accept_encoding_on_putheader(HTTPConnection.putheader)

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.clear()
r = s.post("https://httpbin.org/post")
print(r.json()["headers"])
```

Result:

```json
{'Content-Length': '0',
 'Host': 'httpbin.org',
 'User-Agent': 'python-urllib3/1.26.8',
 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-639e06af-32dea6906aff32526a081e8e'}
```